# Hook up facebook campaigns and google analytics for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, google-analytics, tracking

When creating facebook ads for a website, it is pretty simple to set them up with [utm source](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?&rd=2)-parameters so one can track conversions of the ads and benchmark which one is performing best.

However, even after extensive research, I was not able to figure out how do to that with apps. I guess most approaches wont work since I can not set parameters which are passed "through" the app store process to my app.

In a perfect scenario, I would be able to track a user from the click on the facebook add through the app store until they register in my app. Are there any recommendations, best practices or ideas to be able to do at least part of that, e.g. using Facebook data imported as custom dimension in GA? Would love to hear any ideas, I am pretty much stuck here, since all usual approaches which work fine with webpages obviously will not work with Apps/App Stores.